# How Do I add a row when data is matched in specific columns on different sheets and return value from a specific column when it does?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

On Sheet 1 Column B is job numbers starting at 101.
On Sheet 2 Column A is job numbers sorted from a response sheet and there are multiple duplicates of some job numbers ie, 101
                                            101
                                            102
                                            103
                                            104
                                            105
                                            105
This is because more than one person may end up working on any particular job number and this is the condition that requires a new row to Keep other Data in each job numbers row intact for each form response entry.
Right now im trying:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(if(ISNUMBER(A7:A),VLOOKUP(A7:A,'Sheet 1'!A:AH,1,false)))`
The error i get is cannot find 101 in vlookup.

Answer (score 0):

```
'=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A7:A, 'Sheet 2'!B7:BE,16,False)))'
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.